# Get foreign key field from primary key in another table that linked to many table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2014

My database is designed in SQL Server & I want get output in asp.net, LINQ, C#

I have 2 tables linked to 1 table (1:1)

My question is can I get a primary key linked to which table?

For example:

- tbl_Document (ID, Date, ...)
- tbl_Factor (ID, DocID, ...)
- tbl_Finance (ID, DocID, ...)

What is the best way to know `ID` in `tbl_Document` linked to which table?

I can add record in `tbl_Document` as 'whichTable' and write the name of table in every column, and every time I want to search set "if" and check 'WhichTable'.

Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: You've designed a database inside a database. Chances are that is an anti-pattern. Consider not doing that and instead using referential integrity and traditional FK relationships

Comment: @Jamiec thank you, but what i wana do is: i have some table like bill,  finance & etc and want set a same document number to all of them (add 1 every time). i think the better way is create document table as parent and other table are child.(generalization_ is a part of) from down to up is easy to find document number. but my problem is i wana find from up to down, with document number direct go to linked column. can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you can get only all tables that have foreign key constraints to the parent table:

```
select  object_name(f.referenced_object_id) pk_table, c1.name pk_column_name,
  object_name(f.parent_object_id) fk_table, c2.name fk_column_name
from
sys.foreign_keys f
join sys.columns c1 on c1.object_id = f.referenced_object_id
join sys.columns c2 on c2.object_id = f.parent_object_id 
join sys.foreign_key_columns k 
  on (k.constraint_object_id = f.object_id 
    and c2.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    and c1.column_id = k.referenced_column_id )
where object_name(f.referenced_object_id) ='tbl_Document'
```

There is no such additional information regarding every particular row in parent table. It would be a duplicate information (since you can figure out it by searching in every child table). Thus, as you mentioned you can store child table name in the additional column and then as an option, construct sql dynamically to query child row.

Comment: thanx, its means i should join all column together and then search my key. why there isn't code to direct me to linked column? :)

Comment: Just realized what you really want :) Updated the answer